# Fallo código algoritmo k-NN

Tags: python, machine-learning, inteligencia-artificial

He probado haciendo este código para hacer el algoritmo knn , pero no sé en que estoy fallando.

```
def knn(ejemplo,conjEntrenamiento,k):
    cont=0
    cont1=0
    cont2=0
    x=0
    tmp=0
    for clave in conjEntrenamiento.keys():
        if cont<=k:
            valor = conjEntrenamiento.get(clave);
            distancia = dist(ejemplo,clave);
            valores=list(valor)
            for v in valores:
                if v=="SI":
                    cont1+=1
                else:
                    cont2+=1

            if cont1>cont2:
                    tmp="SI"
            else:
                    tmp="NO"
            cont+=1

    return tmp

def dist(p1,p2):
   return [math.sqrt(sum((x1-x2)**2 for x1,x2 in zip(p1,p2)))];
```

Este es el conjunto de ejemplos , que es un diccionario donde la clave son los puntos y los valores , los valores de clasificacion.

```
KB_knn_1 = 
{(0.1, 0.7, 1.3, 3.4):'SI',
(1.1, 0.8, 2.4, 0.3):'SI',
(2.1, 1.9, 1.5, 0.4):'SI',
(7.1, 0.0, 1.6, 0.5):'SI',
(3.1, 6.1, 1.7, 0.6):'SI',
(1.4, 3.2, 5.8, 0.7):'SI',
(2.1, 5.3, 1.9, 4.8):'NO',
(3.1, 6.2, 5.8, 0.7):'SI',
(4.3, 7.3, 1.9, 4.8):'NO',
(5.3, 8.2, 5.8, 0.7):'SI',
(6.2, 9.3, 1.9, 4.8):'NO',
(7.2, 1.2, 5.8, 0.7):'SI',
(8.2, 2.3, 1.9, 4.8):'NO',
(9.1, 3.2, 5.8, 0.7):'SI',
(5.1, 4.3, 1.9, 4.8):'NO',
(6.1, 0.4, 3.0, 0.9):'NO',
(7.1, 2.5, 1.1, 0.0):'NO',
(1.1, 0.6, 1.2, 0.1):'NO'}
```

Mi salida debe ser 'SI' para los 5 ejemplos mas cercanos a la distancia dada , pero me sale como salida 'NO'

```
knn((0.1,0.7,0.4,1.2),KB_knn_1,5) # Output expected: 'SI'
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo algo raro en tu código, pero la verdad no sabría decir si está bien o mal porque no entiendo qué se supone que debe hacer.

Lo que veo raro es que dentro de `knn` invocas `dist()` para calcular la distancia entre dos puntos, pero después no usas para nada esa distancia. Posiblemente sea un error.

Al margen de eso, lo que sí es un error (y la razón por la que no te funciona) es lo siguiente:

```
        valor = conjEntrenamiento.get(clave);
        # ...
        valores=list(valor)
        for v in valores:
            print(v)
            if v=="SI":
                cont1+=1
            else:
                cont2+=1
```

Fíjate:

- `valor` es lo que extraes del diccionario, y tal como lo tienes será o bien la cadena `'SI'`, o bien la cadena `'NO'`
- `valores=list(valor)` convierte esa cadena en una lista, lo que equivale a separar sus letras. `valores` será o bien la lista `['S', 'I']`, o bien la lista `['N', 'O']`
- Al iterar por esa lista y comparar cada valor con `"SI"`, nunca lo vas a encontrar.

La solución depende de qué pretendías. Si el valor asociado a cada clave es una cadena, la forma correcta de detectar el "SI" sería esta:

```
        valor = conjEntrenamiento.get(clave);
        # ...
        if valor=="SI":
            cont1+=1
        else:
            cont2+=1
```

Si por el contrario el código espera que el valor sea una lista con varias cadenas, alguna de las cuales puede ser `"SI"`, entonces tu código original estaba correcto, pero estaban mal los datos de entrada ya que los valores asociados a cada clave eran cadenas y no listas.

En este caso tendrías que corregir los datos de entrada:

```
KB_knn_1 = {(0.1, 0.7, 1.3, 3.4): ['SI'],
   (1.1, 0.8, 2.4, 0.3): ['SI'],
   (2.1, 1.9, 1.5, 0.4): ['SI'],
   # ...
   (1.1, 0.6, 1.2, 0.1): ['NO']
}
```